# Solve $y'-y=e^{ax}$ for $a \neq 1$ and $a \to 1$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, limits

It's easy to see that this equation is a first order linear differential equation.
$$y'-y=e^{ax}$$
So I find the integrating factor $$e^{\int-1dx}=e^{-x}$$
I multiply the equation with the integratig factor I found so  I get
$$e^{-x}y'-e^{-x}y=e^{ax}e^{-x}\implies (e^{-x}y)'=\int{e^{x(a-1)}}dx$$
$$e^{-x}y=\frac{1}{a-1}e^{x(a-1)}+c\implies y=\frac{1}{a-1}e^{ax}+ce^x$$

Finally the general solution for  $a\neq 1$ is 
$$y=\frac{1}{a-1}e^{ax}+ce^x$$
Now obviously I can not substitute $a$ with $1$ because the denominator will be zero.I believe then that the solution for $a \to 1$ will be the following:$$(\lim_{a \to 1} {\frac{1}{a-1}e^{ax})+ce^x}$$
The limit in the expression above is not a real number, how do I proceed?

Comment: It might be easier to see what's going on as $a\to 1$ by re-writing your solution as
$$
be^x+{e^{ax}-e^x\over a-1},
$$
where $b = c+1/(a-1)$. The parameter $b$ is more natural, as it represents $y(0)$.

Comment: @JohnDawkins I don't understand, how the solution in the above form helps? I mean the limit diverges, do I consider it in my solution for $a=1$ and if yes how?

Comment: The general solution of $y'-y = e^{ax}$ is (by a relabeling of your solution, when $a\not=1$)
$$
y=y(0)e^{x}+{e^{ax}-e^x\over a-1}.
$$
Using l'Hopital's Rule, this converges to $y=y(0)e^x+xe^x$ as $a\to 1$.  This is the general solution of $y'-y=e^x$.

Comment: Because my problem asks to find the general solution for $a=1$ by using the general solution for $a\neq 1$ when $a\to 1$

Comment: @JohnDawkins $y(0)$ as $a \to 1$ does not converge!

Comment: Put another way, the unique solution of the initial value problem
$$
y'-y = e^{ax},\qquad y(0)=b,
$$
is 
$$
y(x) = be^x+{e^{ax}-e^x\over a-1}.
$$
Now keep $b$ fixed and let $a\to 1$.